# iOS translucent status bar not working SDL 2

Tags: ios, sdl, statusbar

I have an app based on SDL2 for iOS. Something in SDL is blocking the translucent status bar from working properly; it always appears as opaque. I've created apps before with a translucent status bar, so I know how it should be setup normally. The problem is with something SDL is changing. Does anyone know the fix to this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the iPad doesn't support the transparent status bar; I was testing on the iPhone simulator before. There wasn't a problem in the first place.